# Why im stuck in a Steamworks SDK SteamFriends function

Tags: c++, steamworks-api

Hi i try to get the the user count from a gameserver with the GetFriendCountFromSource function from the steamworks sdk

```
`
#include <iostream>
#include "..//HeaderFiles/steam_api.h"
#include "..//HeaderFiles/isteamfriends.h"
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    if(SteamAPI_RestartAppIfNecessary(480))
        std::cout << "Hello from Steam!\n";
    uint64 id = 90163946096075782;

    CSteamID steamIDSource(id);

    int nFriends = SteamFriends()->GetFriendCountFromSource(steamIDSource);
       // GetFriendCountFromSource(steamIDSource);
    std::cout << "Hello from Steam!\n";
}`
```

i got the server steam id by calling
[https://api.steampowered.com/IGameServersService/GetServerList/v1/?key=###WEB_API_KEY#####&filter=addr\ip:port](https://api.steampowered.com/IGameServersService/GetServerList/v1/?key=###WEB_API_KEY#####&filter=addr%5Cip:port)

Problem is the code stucks in
SteamFriends()->GetFriendCountFromSource(steamIDSource)

with the error

Unhandled exception at 0x00525ED3 in ConsoleApplication1eeos.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Comment: Post the error message as text instead of as an image and translate it to english.

Comment: thats true sorry i changed it

Answer (score 0):

ok looks like i forgot to add the steamappid.txt and the SteamAPI_Init(); after this its not throwing the exception anymore but the function just gives back 0 even if there r players on this server but iw will do another question for this